# How to upload a site to a server where folders are writable for php

Tags: php, ftp, chmod

This problem occurred to me multiple times now, and it's time for me to do it the right way!

How can I upload a website to the server, where php has access to the folders for writing data.

Usually I use an FTP program, but I can't upload as root, so there are restriction problems all over the place...

How do you do stuff like this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I accidentally added rails to the tags instead off php.

Probably I need to clarify my problem, since the answers didn't really help me out here:

I already have a server running apache, DirectAdmin and some other stuff like rails.

And the problem is when I upload a website like joomla or wordpress via FTP the restrictions always need to be set to 777/775 or these sites can't write to the folders..

So what I need to know is:
How can I upload these sites (via FTP/SSH) as a user (root) that is the same as php, so that php can create files in all folders it needs to write to?

Hope I'm being more clear now, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Well can't clearly understand - but as far as i do, you could upload by ftp and then do some recursive chown on uploaded folder since write permissions usually just come from wrong file owner/group.

Comment: So what you mean is: I put all files/folders to 777, and than use a php-script to chown and chmod all files back to 755?

Comment: I was thinking more in the lines like: 1) upload all via ftp 2) chown folder via ssh to the php user/group.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. But I'm pretty much a noob as it comes to the things, can I do this with one single command-line? And what could be the php user/group?

Comment: Ok, turns out when PHP creates a file the user is 'apache'

Comment: @Tim im also not a pro when it comes down to ssh and that stuff. But if any other wbsites are managed with same user that are running good you could lookup what it is set ther (go to folder of running website and do something like `ls -lsa` and it should show you user/group) Then possibly use that settings on new folder with `chwon user:group /path/to/folder`

Comment: @arma Thanks for that! Did some research myself, and found out that it was apache by looking in DirectAdmin.. I did the chown with -R (found in the --help) on the public_html folder, and after that I did chmod! works like a charm, thanks for helping me out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

1. Upload your site with FTP
2. SSH to the server and go to the `public_html` folder
3. `chown -R [user_name]:[group_name] [folder_name]`

For me the right user was apache..

Answer (score 1):

Use a server with ssh access and full write access to wherever your Rails app is hosted (and usually ssh access is **as** the user that Rails runs as).

For me this usually means a VPS type server, I like [Rackspace Cloud](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/) which turns out to be around $11 - $15 per month for a low traffic, low spec server.  I've also heard good things about [Linode](http://www.linode.com/)

Comment: Linode is a great hosting platform if you have the required knowledge or resources to manage it yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough with the question. I've edited the question, hope you guys can point me in the right direction now.. Thanks!